# Google Maps Javascript API is not showing up on webpage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to utilise a Google Map API on my React/Javascript code within the 'Contact Us' component of my website however the map itself is not showing up. I believe the code is working as the "Loading..." statement appears when the map is loading however when it has loaded in nothing is showing up.

Here's my code in the ContactUs.js file:

```
import React from "react";
import contactuscss from "./ContactUs.module.css";
import Map from "./Map.js";

function ContactUs() {
  return (
    <div className={contactuscss.container}>
      <h2 className={contactuscss.contactus}>CONTACT US</h2>

      <div className={contactuscss.address}>
        <p>Unit 14 Parramatta Business Centre</p>
        <p>2 O'Connell Street</p>
        <p>Parramatta, NSW 2150</p>
        <p>Tel: +61 435 400 290</p>
      </div>

      <form>
        <div className={contactuscss.inputcontainer}>
          <input
            className={contactuscss.nameinput}
            type="text"
            id="name"
            name="name"
            placeholder="Name"
          />

          <input
            className={contactuscss.emailinput}
            type="text"
            id="email"
            name="email"
            placeholder="Email"
          />

          <input
            className={contactuscss.phoneinput}
            type="phone"
            id="phone"
            name="phone"
            placeholder="Phone"
          />

          <textarea
            className={contactuscss.textinput}
            id="message"
            name="message"
            rows="6"
            placeholder="Type your message here..."
          ></textarea>

          <button className={contactuscss.submitbutton} type="submit">
            Submit
          </button>
        </div>

        <div>
          <Map />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ContactUs;
```

And here's the code in the Map.js file:

```
import React from "react";
import { GoogleMap, useLoadScript } from "@react-google-maps/api";

function Map() {
  const { isLoaded } = useLoadScript({
    googleMapsApiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
  });

  if (!isLoaded) return <div>Loading...</div>;

  return (
    <GoogleMap
      zoom={10}
      center={{ lat: 44, lng: -80 }}
      mapContainerClassName={{ width: "100%", height: "100vh" }}
    ></GoogleMap>
  );
}

export default Map;
```

Here's whats in my .env.local file:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY="AIzaSyCH4EPZrF5cvUmM9luEsNdOehQuRyJgAzk"
```

I'm not too sure what is wrong - I've also utilised the most up to date tutorial on youtube for how to upload this API on to my web page.

Answer (score 0):

Few thing to keep in mind as i had also faced the same issue with this map library.

1. First mistake that i see is if you want to apply inline style to the
   map component you need to use **mapContainerStyle** instead of
   **mapContainerClassName** it should be **mapContainerStyle={{...}}**.
2. **mapContainerClassName** only accepts style class names.
3. Even after doing above changes you don't see the map then try giving fixed height and width in the style as it is required for map to render.
4. Do not start loading  untill the google maps scipt loaded. TO acheive this you can use the useLoadScript hook. [useLoadScript Doc](https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/#useloadscript)

[@react-google-maps/api documentation](https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/#googlemap)